# Flutter google maps web memory leak

Tags: flutter, performance, google-maps, flutter-web

Can't clear google maps view in flutter web each time I create new Google maps view the app use more memory ( go to more than 1 G Ram ). appear that the old created map is not disposed or cleared. somehow is still there.
I found an issue already open but on the ios devices.

[Video result memory usage](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EpDjasSqCT9fZETCPFDbGHNufWovv6s7/view?usp=sharing)

Minimum code expample:

```
    class HomeApp extends StatefulWidget {
const HomeApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeApp> createState() => _HomeAppState();
}

class _HomeAppState extends State<HomeApp> {
  final PageController pageController = PageController();

  int selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
        controller: pageController,
        itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
          return MapView(
            title: '$index',
          );
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            selectedIndex = index;
          });
          pageController.jumpTo(index.toDouble());
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.map), label: 
  'Map 1'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.map), label: 
   'Map 2'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

  class MapView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const MapView({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key:
```

key);

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Map $title'),
      ),
      body: const GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition:
            CameraPosition(target: LatLng(33.5731, -7.5898), 
zoom: 5.5),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class MapView extends StatelessWidget {
final String title;
const MapView({Key? key, required this.title})     : super(key: 
key);

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Map $title'),
  ),
  body: const GoogleMap(
    initialCameraPosition:
        CameraPosition(target: LatLng(33.5731, -7.5898), zoom: 
  5.5),
  ),
);
 }
```

}

I'm using:

```
google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.3.2
```

Comment: Please add some code to indicate how you are using Google maps

Comment: Hi, @prasadsunny1 thanks I edit my question and I add more information.

Comment: ` final GeozoneProvider geozoneProvider =
    Provider.of(context);`
Can you also show how you have registered your GeozoneProvider to Provider

Comment: Hi @prasadsunny1 I now what are talking about even I dipose my provider because is not in the top level .

anyway i create a new app with minimum code I will share it with you